# Nosuchelementexception while trying to locate the Play button using Selenium Python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I'm writing a selenium code, but when I want to play a video clicking on the *Play* button, I realized that I can't play it. I used `XPATH`, `CLASS_NAME`, `CSS_SELECTOR` but it failed.

I used this line of code:

```
start_video = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//button[@type='button' and @aria-label='Play' ]").click()
```

shows Nosuchelementexception.

HTML of the element:

```
<button class="ytp-large-play-button ytp-button ytp-large-play-button-red-bg" aria-label="Play"></button>
```

Any help?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  You need to include more details in your code and your explanation.

Comment: Firstly, thank you. I couldn't find any other code structure but there is this one, I used this one: start_video = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//button[@type='button' and @aria-label='Play' ]"). click() i got nosuchelementexception error

Comment: your element might not be loaded. your element might be in an iframe. your element might be obstructed by a pop up or not visible. Try to use ```expected conditions```

Answer (score -1):

Given the HTML:

```
<button class="ytp-large-play-button ytp-button ytp-large-play-button-red-bg" aria-label="Play"></button>
```

To click on the *Play* button ideally you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130336/7429447) for the [*element_to_be_clickable()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54194511/7429447) and you can use either of the following [*locator strategies*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48056120/7429447):

- Using *CSS_SELECTOR*:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button.ytp-large-play-button.ytp-button.ytp-large-play-button-red-bg[aria-label='Play']"))).click()
  ```
- Using *XPATH*:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[@class='ytp-large-play-button ytp-button ytp-large-play-button-red-bg' and @aria-label='Play']"))).click()
  ```
- **Note**: You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

Comment: First of all, thank you for your answer. I tried both of the codes you gave, but the result was disappointing again. This is Exactly My Error Code:

Comment: WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button.ytp-large-play-) button.ytp-button.ytp-large-play-button-red-bg[aria-label='Play']"))).click()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/support/wait.py", line 95, in until
    raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:
stacktrace:
RemoteError
WebDriverError
NoSuchElementError
element.find/

Comment: @dax Which website are you looking at? Is it a public url? Youtube? Share the link please.